# xCode 5: I'm getting a small translucent square on UIButton selection

Tags: xcode, uibutton, interface-builder, highlight

If this is an Interface Builder issue, the solution has eluded me for days. I'm getting this weird translucent square on my UIButtons when they are selected, and I have no idea how to get rid of it. The buttons are not custom, they are "system" style buttons, and they are just simple rectangles.

I've tried changing every setting I can think of including "adjusts image on highlight" with no luck.

Here's a screenshot of the culprit (happens on both buttons)

[image]

And here are my button settings:

[image]

Comment: Same problem, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, set the button type to Custom (in place of system) solved the problem. But I still don't know what is this strange blue square.